# CSS sticky footer trouble

Tags: php, html, css

I have a little problem with my footer on a new website I am building.
I tried the technique from Ryan Fait (http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), but somehow it just won't work out. maybe you can help me and tell me why?

The link to my page is aev.martenzander.com

I only tried it on the index.php, so dont get confused when visiting subpages.

CODE:

HTML

```
<!-- FOOTER -->
<div class="stickyfooter"></div>
<div class="footer">
    <footer>
        <?php
        include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
    </footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.footer{
        height: 111px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }

.stickyfooter{
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        margin: 0 auto -111px;
    }
```

Comment: Nope. Add your code here and we can help

Comment: Okay, added the code now ;)

Comment: You mentioned you are using Ryan Fait's example, but your structure differs dramatically from his. You might try his tutorial again.

Comment: @showdev , thanks man, shame on me! I forgot that push class.
Well for me it was kinda confusing because for me a wrapper is a div or another element wrapping arround another. this "wrapper" is actually just before the actual footer, so that was kinda strange, but figured it out now;)

Comment: Nice job! @tsHunter has the right idea. The "wrapper" wraps around everything except the footer. The "push" element is the last child of the "wrapper".

Comment: yes, it makes sense to me now;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the way it works is you have a mainWrapper class with a set negative margin, then you have a push class which forces that margin to stay clear always, then you have a footer class that occupies that margin.

Right now you have no push class, and your footer class is defined within the wrapper. It needs to be outside the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link with an easy solution:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

The HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```